Typescript interface instance values are individually undefined
I am a JavaScript and React noob. I am creating a project using TypeScript, React, Sequelize, and postgres for the database.
I am trying to access a request.body member quantity in my post route using Fastify. I am passing the type of the body to Fastify in my post middleware. When I console.log() the entire body, I can see the correct quantity, but when I extract the quantity individually, the value is undefined.
interface IMyInterfaceCreateBody {
  quantity: number;
}

interface IMyInterfacePostReply {
  200: { items: MyObject[] };
  201: { items: MyObject[] };
  302: { url: string };
  '4xx': { error: string };
}

const myRoute: FastifyPluginAsync = (fastify): Promise<void> => {
  fastify.post<{
    Body: IMyInterfaceCreateBody;
    Reply: IMyInterfacePostReply;
  }>('/myRoute', async function (request, reply) {
    const newItems: MyObject[] = [];
    const body: IMyInterfaceCreateBody = request.body;
    console.log(body);
    const quantity: number = body.quantity;
    console.log(quantity);
    for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
      const newMyObject = await MyObject.create({
        id: uuid(),
      });
      console.log(newMyObject);
      newItems.push(newMyObject);
    }
    await reply.code(201).send({ items: newItems });
  });

  return Promise.resolve();
};

Console output:
[App] {"quantity":1}
[App] undefined

I believe this may have to do with using a Fastify hook to extract raw data, but am unsure.
I have tried:

extracting the quantity value directly into a variable typed number

first extracting putting the entire body into an interface instance and extracting the quantity value individually, but the value becomes undefined


I expect the value of quantity that I pass when using the post route.

Can you share ow do you extract the request body? by itself the code seems ok, which might indicate that request body might not be extracted properly

The solution was simply setting the headers parameter in my request to 'Content-Type: application/json' on the client-side.
